# Freeing heap on exit in C automatically

Tags: c, memory

I have an assignment where my functions `foo` and `bar` are going to be tested, both of which allocate memory on the heap.
The thing is, I'm not allowed to change `int main`. If the examiner calls `foo` and/or `bar` in `int main`, then how am I meant to deallocate this space (since I can't change `main`)?

I was thinking about adding a function call on program termination, but isn't this only possible if I define that function call in `main` (which I can't edit)?

Comment: There is `atexit`. But all memory is freed on exit anyway (at least on systems with memory virtualization like your desktop machine).

Comment: On most systems you don't need to free the memory the the program exits. It is taken care of automatically. And some prefer no to do it as it makes program exit a little slower...

Comment: While on a normal PC-like system these days (and since many years back) it's not needed to free memory allocations, I would argue that it's a "Good Habit™" to clean up after yourself anyway. :) And I also argue that you should have explicit code to clean up after yourself in all cases of normal program exit (if your program crashes then don't bother, especially since the data could be corrupted anyway).

Comment: Since we can't see any of your code we're reduced to wild guessing. My wild guess is that you do not actually need to allocate any heap memory. But I could be wrong!

Comment: But the thing is, he want's us to deallocate all memory allocated on the heap before exit.

Comment: Is there a way in which I can set a destructor to call after main, without defining the destructor in main?

Comment: As for the assignment itself, it's very likely as guessed by @ZanLynx, that you don't actually have to do dynamic allocation. Remember that C have variable-length arrays if you really need it. Or worst case there's `alloca` to allocate off the stack. Since you don't tell us the assignment you need to solve there's really not much we can help with.

Comment: Do the functions return allocated memory to the function that calls them, or is the allocated memory only used internally?

Comment: You should reformulate the question. There is just too little information to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: You could also use function mocking: `#define bar() puts("please teach us some useful knowledge instead"); bar();/*actual function call*/ free(foo_leak); free(bar_leak);`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 'I would argue that it's a "Good Habit™" to clean up after yourself anyway'....?  Writing, compiling, linking, testing and debugging redundant code is a good habit?

Comment: 'You must clean up all allocated memory before exiting' is now the most pervasive and dangerous cargo-cult nonsense on SO and, aparrently, on current programming courses.  It's not even sensibly possible with non-trivial multithreaded apps.  The only justification I've seen is dubious and speculative mumbles about 'may cause a problem if an incompetent developer copies the code without knowing how it works':(

Comment: @MartinJames: I disagree. "Use `strncpy`" is a more dangerous cargo-cultism, but there is lots of competition for the title. This one is certainly in the list, though.

Comment: @rici maybe.  Sure, several str* library calls are ummm...'less than optimal'  though my CC spans multiple languages:)

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking about adding a function call on program termination, but isn't this only possible if I define that function call in `main` (which I can't edit)?

No, it is not the case that the only way to have a function called at program termination is to modify `main()`.  C has the concept of "exit handlers" -- functions that are registered in advance to be called when the program exits.  Appropriate functions are registered as exit handlers via the [`atexit()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) function.

But perhaps you are overthinking this.  Even if the functions under test must dynamically allocate memory without freeing it before they terminate (and you should carefully consider whether that's really the case), it is not erroneous or even problematic, in an operational sense, for the program to terminate without freeing that memory.  The operating system will clean up any remaining allocated memory.  Only if your program is being evaluated on whether it cleans up all allocated memory, and you have no other way to do it, should you be looking at exit handlers.

Comment: Yeah, the OS exterminates the entire C sub-allocator heap without any consideration of malloc(), free() etc.  In that respect, it does.indeed 'clean up any remaining allocated memory':)

Answer (score 1):

First I should point out that doing this is kind of useless because as others have said the operating system is going to clean all of your program out of memory on exit.

But anyway.

Have some fun with this. You'll have to modify this to register the cleanup pointers in your own functions instead of main.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

static void **free_ptr_vec;
static size_t free_ptr_vec_len;

static void onexit_free_ptrs(void) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < free_ptr_vec_len; i++) {
    free(free_ptr_vec[i]);
  }
  free(free_ptr_vec);
  free_ptr_vec = NULL;
  free_ptr_vec_len = 0;
}

void add_free_ptr(void *ptr) {
  if (free_ptr_vec == NULL) {
    atexit(onexit_free_ptrs);
  }
  free_ptr_vec_len++;
  free_ptr_vec = realloc(free_ptr_vec, sizeof *free_ptr_vec * free_ptr_vec_len);
  free_ptr_vec[free_ptr_vec_len - 1] = ptr;
}

int main() {
  void *p = malloc(4000);
  add_free_ptr(p);
  p = malloc(16);
  add_free_ptr(p);
  return 0;
}
```